# How to auto-deploy Play Framework (2.4) application locally with Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, typesafe-activator, playframework-2.4, test-environments

How can I auto-deploy Play Framework (2.4) application with Jenkins locally on the same server Jenkins is running? At some point we're going to set up a proper production environment separately and will probably implement test environment(s) in the same way but at this point I'd like to check out whether it is possible to set up a simple test environment to the same server Jenkins is running.

I have a Jenkins job running tests and it seems to work OK. Basically "Execute shell" running activator commands (that could be combined to one line).

```
./activator clean
./activator test
```

With Play 1 I've used `play start` & `play stop` for similar things. Trying `activator start` on my dev env, I get the message:

```
The start command is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version of Play.
To run Play in production mode, run 'stage' instead, and then execute the generated start script in target/universal/stage/bin.
To test your application using production mode, run 'testProd' instead.
```

So I evaluated two (incomplete) alternatives with "Execute shell" & stage:

Stage & run with nohup:

```
./activator clean
./activator stage
nohup target/universal/stage/bin/my-app -Dplay.evolutions.db.default.autoApply=true
```

-> application started OK but the Jenkins task did not stop.

Stage & run with nohup on background:

```
./activator clean
./activator stage
nohup target/universal/stage/bin/my-app -Dplay.evolutions.db.default.autoApply=true &
```

-> application seems to have started to some point but did not keep on running?

What would be the preferred (or even only working) way here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the particular case I ended up using Docker:

- Installed Docker to the server
- Created a Dockerfile based on [play-docker-ci](https://github.com/adamalex/play-docker-ci)
- Configured Jenkins to

  - build Docker image
  - stop existing container if running, remove existing container if exists
  - run Docker image

and this seems to work pretty nicely so far.

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins kills all its child processes when build finishes to avoid memory leaks, thus there is no app running. The easiest way to setup jenkins with `Playframework 2.4` is to use `sbt` tasks and [sbt plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/sbt+plugin). If you want to perform a release from jenkins, the best way would be to build [debian package](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager) and install it using jenkins shell - no process would be killed. See [release plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Release+Plugin).

Comment: Thanks, even though I ended up to Docker, this seems to be relevant idea. Play docs have also info on this on  [Production / The Native Packager](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Production#The-Native-Packager)

Answer (score 0):

I set this up by having Team City generate a startup.sh script that contains the command to start up the Play server as a background process:

```
nohup /pathToApp/bin/app_name -Dhttp.port=8180 &
```

Then the next build step just runs this shell script and starts it up. The ***nohup*** and ***&*** make this run as a background process and when the build server disconnects it will keep running. I cut out a lot of extra stuff from the startup script for clarity sake, but you can just add [whatever startup parameters](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ProductionConfiguration) you want to use for your application.